# Accessing variables in other classes (Java)

Tags: java, class

Why doesn't the following program return **0**, since I am accessing **p** from a **new A()**, which has not had **main** called on it?

```
 public class A {

         public static int p = 0;

         public static void main(String[] args) {

                p = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
                new B().go();

            }

        }


       class B {
            public void go() {
                System.out.println(new A().p);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the output? Any errors?

Comment: That won't compile, p is a member variable, main is a static method

Comment: Please try to post questions here which seem valid. I suppose you didn't even try to check whether the program would first compile or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>That should not even compile.</strike>

Probably you had `p` as static  and than you change it. The way it is written now, doesn't compile.

```
$ javac A.java 
A.java:7: non-static variable p cannot be referenced from a static context
            p = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            ^
1 error
```

**edit**

Now that you have corrected your code the answer is:

This program doesn't print **0** because what you see is the value assigned in line 7. In this case `p` is a class variable.

```
 p = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
```

So when you execute:

```
 System.out.println(new A().p);
```

And you expect to see `0` thinking the "new A" will have it own copy of `p` but is not the case.

Comment: good call. In the original code p is static. That probably resolves the issue.

Comment: I'd delete this question, but I can't.

Comment: @George: If you run it with `0` as argument, it prints `0` ;)

Comment: In that case.. mhhh nevermind :P You can always mark my answer as accepted and I'll in turn vote to close it.

Comment: Thank you. So the key is the word "static" (which, ironically, is the one word that I must've erased when I pasted the code!)

Comment: Yeap. I have voted to close this as "not a real question" ( the reason: "not longer relevant" is not available anymore )

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't even compile, since you're trying to assign an instance member from a static method.

Answer (score 0):

This program doesn't compile. The compiler won't let you access 'p' from within the main method of class A. You cant access non static variables from within a static context. Hence the compilation issue

Comment: Even if you define the variable 'p' to be static, still there is a run time exception `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`

Answer (score 0):

That won't compile as is, so I don't know how it would return anything.

Variable p cannot be accessed from a static context is what it SHOULD say.

If you set an instance of p, it should work correctly.

ps.  For this one experiment I will let you have a public non-final member variable, but NEVER AGAIN!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: this was just a guess based on the first revision of the question, which assumes p is non-static. It turns out that the intent was that it is static, so this gets the wrong end of the stick.

Despite the compiler error, I assume your intent was to initialize p from a non-static method, or on an instance of A.

The problem is then that you are creating a new instance of A in B, and not using the original instance.

To get what (I believe) you want, do something like

```
   public class A {

         public int p = 0;

         public static void main(String[] args) {
                A a = new A();
                a.p = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
                new B().go(a);
         }

   }


       class B {
            public void go(A a) {
                System.out.println(a.p);
            }
        }
```

Note that the go() method in B takes A as a parameter. No new instance of A is created.